# Scraping bond data from Wall Street Journal using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some data from the WSJ markets page using Beautiful Soup but always get Status Code=404 Page not found message. My code works fine on other websites so what's going wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/bond/BX/TMBMKJP-10Y?mod=md_bond_govt_bonds_quote'
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
print('Page status code',page.status_code)
```

Comment: My guess is you have to send some headers such as user-agent

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @SteveB follow my below code. I think, it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `headers`. You can try it:

```
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}

url='https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/bond/BX/TMBMKJP-10Y?mod=md_bond_govt_bonds_quote'

page=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Cool, that works. I guess this protects against bots. Thanks